# flash cs3 component problem

Tags: flash, components, cs3, swc

I have been using custom swc based components for my new flash game. I was nearly through with the engine development when I decided to update some of my placeholder graphics. I made the necessary changes only to find that my component wouldn't compile. I found this strange because I merely updated the graphics and some non-essential code needed to display the new graphics.  Perhaps I changed a setting...? I fixed the problems the compiler reported and exported the new swc file. Success. I reloaded my components panel and dragged it on to the stage... Only to find an empty component! The component didn't even register in my library.  It simply disappeared! Any suggestions? It's in as3 by the way.

Comment: You might need to go into more detail - what errors did you get? what platform are you coding in? What version(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.  I was using FLINT to display some particles, and the inclusion of this library caused my component to compile incorrectly.  I have no idea why this happened, and this seems like a glitch with flash cs3.  It seems like the components in cs3 were very rushed together because I have experienced other problems like this before.  I just hope that this is the last one I run into...